# Promises and Observables - intermediate methods

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service that I want to build an abstraction over.

The service returns `Observable<DataAlert>`, and I want to basically "pass" that on, while making a separate call to [a devextreme custom dialog](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/utils/ui/dialog/#customoptions). I am not sure what the show() method for this returns - my guess is a Promise.

In an ideal world, my method would be awaitable and return a DataAlert. I know that I can use `firstValueFrom` to turn the observable (which only emits one value) into a value and await it, but I am struggling with the method for the whole thing.

I currently have:

```
snooze(alert: DataAlert) : Observable<DataAlert> {
  var obs = new Observable<DataAlert>(sub => {
    // this calls a custom dialog and returns a Promise<Date>
    this.getDate().then((date) => {
      this.alertService.snooze(alert.id, date).subscribe((result) => {
        sub.next(result);
      });
    });
  });
  return obs;
}
```

This works, but it feels like there is a better way? Could anyone recommend a better approach?

Comment: You can try to use RxJS. 
"switchMap" would be a better option.
Check here - https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `this.getDate()` into a Observable via `from` and then switch to the `alertService.snooze()` observable via `switchMap`. Like this:

```
snooze(alert: DataAlert): Observable<DataAlert> {
    return from(this.getDate()).pipe(
        switchMap((date) => {
            return this.alertService.snooze(alert.id, date);
        })
    );
}
```

Then you can call it:

```js
snooze(alert).subscribe(result => { /* Do something */ });
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe, if `snooze` doesn't by itself.

Comment: This seems to cover the bases for what I'm after - thanks - I am new to Angular so I will work thru the things you have done and revert - but many thanks :)

Comment: Works great thanks and I like that I can convert the promise and then merge with the switchMap - make sense and understandable. Thanks vm